# Force embedded Java applet to use external proxy

Tags: proxy, java

I've configured my browser to use an external proxy for all traffic. It works well except when I visit a certain site with an embedded java game. The traffic sent from the java applet is not going through the proxy (I know this because the app displays my real IP address).

I've tried changing relevant java settings but I can't get it to use the proxy.

Can anyone suggest a way I can route traffic from the applet through a proxy, without restricting the functionality of the game? In linux or windows. All other http traffic is going through the proxy just fine.

Comment: It's a little bit odd trying to answer a question when you don't provide the Java Version, Operating system, browser, proxy software, is it a SOCKS proxy, is it your applet, is it HTTP traffic for the game, ...

Comment: Java version/OS/browser can be any, it still doesn't work. Currently not using any proxy software, just setting IP/port of the proxy in control panel which forces http/https and maybe some other traffic through the proxy. Not sure what protocol/port the game uses but it could be something random.

Comment: Unknown protocol/port --> not HTTP --> not "proxyable"

Comment: @mailq why is that?

Comment: Because you don't tell me what proxy you have. And therefore I assume it is only a HTTP proxy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: The applet doesn't use HTTP traffic but uses some other protocol on a different port. So this isn't possible if the programmer didn't take this into account.

Comment: If the game uses some non-standard port and a different protocol, does the proxy have to be set up specifically for this? Why can't I tell the proxy to forward the traffic regardless? (sorry for my lack of understanding)

Comment: As I said: depends on the proxy. A HTTP-Proxy is **only** for HTTP.